# Key value pair getting removed automatically in swift 4 while writing to it using network calls

Tags: swift

I am running multiple network calls simultaneously and storing the results in a dictionary. For some items, I am able to first write it to the dictionary which then later is getting removed when more writes are done. To be precise, I am making 5 calls simultaneously, the result of the first call is written to the dictionary, then it's removed and the dictionary contains the result of the remaining 4 service calls.

Comment: Please add some code snippet to help explaining your problem.

Comment: This could be because of race conditions if you're writing from multiple queues, or it could be a simpler problem of stomping on your own data on a single queue. I suspect the former, but we'll need to see how you're updating the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, it was because multiple threads were writing to the dictionary. Fixed it by initializing the dictionary with key:nil as AnyObject pairs.